# which customer number(numbers) occur max time in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table ORDERS which has something like this value ,

```
customerNumber | orderNumber(PK)
   40                 1
   30                 2
   40                 3
   20                 4
   30                 5
```

So, this table has customerNumbers 40 and 30 placing the max orders. Can anyone tell me a MySQL query to return the customerNumber (numbers), i dont want the count of the orders, just want the customer (cutomers) with the max order placed .

Thanks.

Comment: Add the expected result and what you have tried so far

Comment: i want to write a query to get the customer numbers 40,30 , but i dont have a clue how to proceed

Comment: so you just want 40 and 30, no one else, and you want, say, the count of their orders

Comment: yes just 40,30 . not the count of their orders . actual data is very huge, this is just a sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should get deservedly flamed for this, but hey, the sun's out and it's feeling like a good day...

```
SELECT x.customernumber 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT customernumber
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY customernumber
     ) x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) total 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY customernumber 
        ORDER 
           BY total DESC 
        LIMIT 1
     ) y 
    ON y.total = x.total;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below statement to get the Customer who placed maximum orders.

```
SELECT customerNumber FROM orders
GROUP BY customerNumber
ORDER BY COUNT(orderNumber) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: yes i was able to make this query, but what if their are more then one customer with the highest order , LIMIT 1 wont work